# Compare two values in SQL with a comparison in between columns

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have two columns to compare. I am writing a query in Oracle SQL

I need a query to check the value of the first column if it is between +/- 5% of the second column.

Ex: If value in column B is 500, Column A should be between 525 and 475

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE a BETWEEN b*0.95 AND b*1.05
```

Comment: @user1028250: remember that if you find an answer solved (or helped to solve) your question, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. Thanks